# Time traveling boy takes girl to two-caste future, where the rich live on buildings with stilts

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I hardly remember anything about the series, except that a girl meets a boy from the future, and he takes her back there. The society has become double-tiered, with the rich living on a new surface that's been built on stilts all across the world, whilst the poor still live on the ground, and have access to much sparser resources.

Body-morphing is also really easy in this world, and I remember the boy persuading her to get a slimmer and more curvaceous body. I also have a vague recollection that at least one of the books was bound back-to-back, so it had two front covers and no back cover. I read it in the early 00s/late 90s, and I don't think the books were particularly old at the time. They were definitely marketed as fantasy/sci fi light trash for teen/pre teen girls.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! Thanks for asking this good question. So we can help more, when did you read this?

Comment: Reminds me of the Uglies series of books, but I don't think they involve time travel. They are set in the future though.

Comment: The book being bound back-to-back w/ another makes it sound like a Tor double: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_Double_Novels

Comment: Or Ace SF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ace_double_novels

Comment: Vaguely reminds me of the Star Trek episode "Cloudminders" or the novel/film https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_%28novel%29

Comment: Reminds me of an Asimov story (I think).  No time travelling, but the rich lived in the "upper" side of the city, much as you describe.

Comment: "Pretty sure I'm looking for the same book as this person. scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34337/… – Lydia Mar 17 '16 at 22:01"

from https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122274

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like *A Woman on the Edge of Time* by Marge Piercy

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/044900094X)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woman_on_the_Edge_of_Time)

Plot Spoilers!

> It's the woman who actually does the time traveling. She journeys to 2 possible futures. The one you describe is her second trip. In this future, she meets a cyborg named Cash and a woman who live in a city high up on stilts.

Comment: It sadly is not, it was a lot more trashy than that.