# Book in 90s/early 00s with time travel/world shifting with two tier society

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm trying to remember a name of a book or the author that I read in the late 90s/early 00s. I read a lot by the same author, and she seemed to specialise in teen scifi/fantasy with romance. A lot of her books had a feature where you could read them in either direction and you got the story from someone else's perspective. So basically two books in one, one starting from the front, the other from the back.

Specific elements I remember from one of them are the girl either travelling forward in time or side stepping worlds, (pretty sure it was the former) where she meets a boy (or he takes her through, again, not clear), he takes into some kind of body morphing booth so she can look like the people there. The future has a two tier society where the rich live really high in the air, and are slim and beautiful, the buildings were build on massive stilts and eventually there were roads and stuff built up there too. The down below are less genetically blessed and live in poverty on the old level roads.

I'm pretty sure it's not any of the Ace doubles or Tor back to backs because both sides were by the same author about the same events. I think the covers were green and yellow with a boy's face on one side and a girl's face on the other.

Comment: Pretty sure I'm looking for the same book as this person. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34337/time-traveling-boy-takes-girl-to-two-caste-future-rich-live-on-buildings-with-s

Comment: I answered the question you linked to. I think it's _A Woman on the Edge of Time_ by Marge Piercy. If so, let me know and I'll add my answer here or figure out how to link these two questions.

Comment: Oh I wish it was that one, it’s definitely not. This was more teenage trash than feminist classics.